# Using TryFrom<T> in a generic way and dealing with lifetimes in a generics

Tags: rust, lifetime

Unable to generalized extracting data using TryFrom

I am trying to extract data using TryFrom, where there is a header, data, and footer.
However, I am fighting with lifetimes.

My gist of this code.
https://gist.github.com/rustafarian-dev/4ef1219f6b87e6d34cd22b901dc3dab7

It is a simplified version of what I am trying to do.

The basic idea is a generalized struct that wraps the data extraction.

```
struct MyData<T>(String, T, String);

impl <'a, 'b, T> TryFrom<&'a mut DataReader<'b>> for MyData<T>
where
T: TryFrom<&'a mut DataReader<'b>>,
T::Error: From<ErrorKind>,
{
    type Error = T::Error;
    fn try_from(r: &'a mut DataReader<'b>) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        let a = String::try_from(r.as_mut())?;
        let b = T::try_from(r.as_mut())?;
        let c = String::try_from(r.as_mut())?;
        Ok(MyData(a, b, c))
    }
}
```

The compiler error

```
   Compiling test_borrow v0.1.0 (/root/Projects/test_borrow)
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*r` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:56:34
   |
47 | impl <'a, 'b, T> TryFrom<&'a mut DataReader<'b>> for MyData<T>
   |       -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
55 |         let b = T::try_from(r.as_mut())?;
   |                             ----------
   |                             |
   |                             first mutable borrow occurs here
   |                             argument requires that `*r` is borrowed for `'a`
56 |         let c = String::try_from(r.as_mut())?;
   |                                  ^^^^^^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0499`.
error: could not compile `test_borrow` (bin "test_borrow" test) due to previous error
```

Comment: You can fix this simply by swapping the `let b = ...` and `let c = ...` lines. Strings are owned data types, so they don't create borrows. Only `b` creates a borrow of `r`, so if you do that last, it's fine.

Comment: The order of extraction matters.

Comment: You can't do this with your current design. See also [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/r3bew2/how_to_let_rust_know_that_a_mutable_borrow_no/). I'd refactor the `DataReader` to own `data` to get rid of borrowing.

Comment: I ended up changing my design.
I was able to get this to work using higher-rank lifetimes.
But that caused a different set of problems.